# ¿Implementar & background en mi propio shell en C?

Tags: c, shell

Estoy intentando crear mi propia shell en C, hasta ahora he conseguido que me haga todo lo que necesito correctamente pero estoy buscando la manera de implementar la sincronización asíncrona de cuando se escribe & detrás de una sentencia o comando (también llamado background), que el shell no espere la finalización del proceso hijo sino que siga esperando nuevas ordenes del usuario como hace el shell de linux normalmente. Les dejo mi código a ver si alguien me puede ayudar, supongo que tengo que hacer algo con el waitpid. Muchas gracias de antemano.

PD: También necesito que al escribir & se muestre el PID del proceso que se genera, igual que hace el shell de unix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <libgen.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <ctype.h>  

#define TAM 1000 

void  parseo(char *line, char **argv);
char* normalizar(char *str);

int main(void) {

    char  cad[TAM];             
    char  *argv[TAM]; 
    char  *to;

    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    while (1) {                   

        printf("user@PC $: ");    
        fgets(cad, TAM, stdin);

        // Si encontramos un salto de linea (se pulsa enter)
        if (cad[strlen(cad) - 1] == '\n')                                                           
            cad[strlen(cad) - 1] = '\0';    // lo marcamos como final de sentencia    

        // Si no se escribe nada, se espera
        if (strlen(cad) == 0) continue;

        // Parseamos lo introducido en el shell
        parseo(cad, argv);

        // Normalizamos los comandos
        normalizar((char*)argv[0]);

        // Exit para salir del shell
        if (!strcmp(argv[0], "exit")) exit(0);  

        // Implementación del comando CD
        if (!strcmp(argv[0], "cd")){

            to = argv[1];
            // Retorno al directorio anterior
            if(argv[1] == NULL) chdir("..");

            chdir(to);
            continue;
        }            
        // Creamos el proceso
        pid = fork();

        if (pid  < 0) { 
            printf("Error al crear los procesos \n");
            exit(1);

        } else if (pid == 0) {   
            // Ejecutamos los comandos, a no ser que sea erroneo
            if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) {
                printf("%s: no se encontró la orden \n", argv[0]);
                exit(1);
            }
        }else {  

            waitpid(pid,&status,0);
        }   

    }
    return 0;
}

void  parseo(char *line, char **argv){

    while (*line != '\0') {       
        while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')

            *line++ = '\0';     
            *argv++ = line; 

        while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n') 
            line++;             
    } 
    *argv = '\0';    
}

char* normalizar(char *str){

    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)str;

    while (*p) {
        *p = tolower((unsigned char)*p);
        p++;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Michael, tu pregunta es muy amplia. Divide tu problema en partes más pequeñas y manejables y haz todas las preguntas que necesites. Lee esta guía [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Tengo entendido que la operación de crear un nuevo proceso separado desde uno ya existente consiste en éstos pasos:

1. Crear un duplicado "hijo" del proceso inicial con la función `fork()`. Esta le proporciona al proceso padre el PID del proceso hijo. El proceso hijo recibe un 0 como PID. De esta manera tu código puede saber quién es ahora, ya que ambos, padre e hijo, continúan ejecutando concurrentemente las siguientes instrucciones del programa después del retorno de fork().
2. El proceso hijo así creado se sustituye a sí mismo con el nuevo proceso deseado usando alguna de las funciones `exec()`. Este nuevo proceso hereda, entre otras cosas, el PID de quien lo ejecuta, los descriptores de archivo, etc.
3. El proceso padre supervisa los cambios de estado del nuevo proceso hijo usando alguna de las funciones `wait()` y puede, como parte del ciclo primario, informar de esos cambios al usuario, enviar a su vez señales al proceso para pararlo (implementar la orden kill) o suspenderlo (implementar la tecla de suspensión ^Z), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de [`waitpid`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/es/man2/wait.2.html):

> La función waitpid suspende la ejecución del proceso en curso hasta
>   que
>          un  hijo especificado por el argumento pid ha terminado, o hasta que se
>          produce una señal cuya acción es finalizar el proceso actual o llamar a
>          la función manejadora de la señal.

Es decir que lo ocurre es que tu proceso se detendrá hasta que finalice el que acabas de invocar con `&`. A no ser que quieras desarrollar toda la lógica para manejar las llamada a procesos en segundo plano, una alternativa sería hacer algo así: `system("ls &");` el problema de esto es que delegas el manejo del proceso al shell original y no al tuyo.

Comment: Estoy intentando evitar el shell original y system(), he estado mirando algo llamado daemon con setsid() y demás para tratar procesos en background pero no logro entenderlo del todo.

Comment: Efectivamente implementar lo que buscas nos es trivial y excede seguramente el marco de una respuesta en este sitio.